# Black spots in render view, while material view shows correctly

Tags: texturing

This is my model in material view:

[image]

This is how it looks like in render view:

[image]

As you can see, there are alot of black spots.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occured because the object has multiple UV-Maps and the wrong was selected for rendering:

[image]

I was able to solve it by clicking on the camera symbol of the correct UV-Map.